# Convert bitmap array to YUV (420planar)?

Tags: android, image-processing, rgb, android-image, yuv

How can I convert Bitmap created using getDrawingCache() to YUV420planar format ?

The bitmap is created from a custom view like this

```
view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(board.getDrawingCache(), 320, 240, true);
board.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

This question is similar but doesn't give the same format that I am looking for.
[Convert bitmap array to YUV (YCbCr NV21)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960247/convert-bitmap-array-to-yuv-ycbcr-nv21).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A bit of reading into YUV formats helped me figure it out. I just had to modify a tiny bit of the code linked above. For anyone who has the same doubt

```
void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;
    
        int yIndex = 0;
        int uIndex = frameSize;
        int vIndex = frameSize+((yuv420sp.length-frameSize)/2);
        System.out.println(yuv420sp.length+" "+frameSize);
        
    
        int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
    
                a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;
    
                // well known RGB to YUV algorithm
                
                Y = ( (  66 * R + 129 * G +  25 * B + 128) >> 8) +  16;
                U = ( ( -38 * R -  74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ( ( 112 * R -  94 * G -  18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128; 
    
                // NV21 has a plane of Y and interleaved planes of VU each sampled by a factor of 2
                //    meaning for every 4 Y pixels there are 1 V and 1 U.  Note the sampling is every other
                //    pixel AND every other scanline.
                yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) { 
                    yuv420sp[uIndex++] = (byte)((U<0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                    yuv420sp[vIndex++] = (byte)((V<0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                }
    
                index ++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You only dealt with one case for semi-planar format: half Y, quarter size U, quarter size V. On devices with planar format: half Y, half UV pairs, you'll have to use the linked code (with UV order flipped).

Comment: What should be size of yuv420sp? I am using (3*width*height)/2 but it's not working correctly.