# Bitmap to MP4 green stripes in Pixel 3

Tags: android-bitmap, android-mediacodec, mediamuxer

I'm developing an application that has a feature that converts from an array list of Bitmap Images into MP4 video. I used MediaMuxer and MediaCodec to do this. Everything works fine on almost all devices except some Pixel Devices (e.g. Pixel 6 worked very well, but Pixel 3 can't). The result in Pixel 3 was a green stripe. I searched and read many articles but nothing related to this. Can someone suggest me a solution? Thanks

[This is a screen shot of video exported in Pixel 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIX8u.png)

This the config that I used:

```
      MediaCodec videoCodec = MediaCodec.createEncoderByType(MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC);
      MediaFormat videoFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIMETYPE_VIDEO_AVC, width, height);
      videoFormat.setInteger(KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
      videoFormat.setInteger(KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
      videoFormat.setInteger(KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, I_FRAME_INTERVAL);
      videoFormat.setInteger(KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible);
      videoFormat.setInteger(KEY_MAX_INPUT_SIZE, MAX_INPUT_SIZE);
      videoCodec.configure(videoFormat, null, null, CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
      videoCodec.start();
      mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFilePath, MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
```

Config value:

```
  BIT_RATE = 1000000;
  FRAME_RATE = 20;
  I_FRAME_INTERVAL = 5;
  MAX_INPUT_SIZE = 10485760; // 10 MB
```

Note: My boss don't want to use ffmpeg

Comment: In what format do you pass the images to the codec? You declare the color format as `COLOR_FormatYUV420Flexible` which is standard for video, but bitmaps are normally RGB (not YUV).

Comment: Thanks, @dev.bmax. It's one of the reasons that cause the problems. Besides, I read and tried many solutions and finally solved this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I read and tried many solutions and finally solved this.
Some note:

- Try to detect the appropriate [Color Format](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities) instead of setting a fixed value
- Some old devices like Pixel 3 don't support Semi-planar YUV format (which causes green stripes in the result), so we should use Planar YUV format (e.g. `COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar`)
- Sometimes the result looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703596/mediacodec-and-camera-colorspaces-dont-match)

Below is the solution that solved all the above problems created by combining 2 solutions in Stackoverflow thanks to @OldSchool4664, @shervinox([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51278232/14561533)) and @monster-brain ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66902368/14561533))

**Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51278232/14561533) for full usage, I only provide modified BitmapToVideoEncoder class**

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.media.MediaCodec;
import android.media.MediaCodecInfo;
import android.media.MediaCodecList;
import android.media.MediaFormat;
import android.media.MediaMuxer;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentLinkedQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;

public class BitmapToVideoEncoder {
    private static final String TAG = BitmapToVideoEncoder.class.getSimpleName();

    private IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback mCallback;
    private File mOutputFile;
    private Queue<Bitmap> mEncodeQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue();
    private MediaCodec mediaCodec;
    private MediaMuxer mediaMuxer;

    private Object mFrameSync = new Object();
    private CountDownLatch mNewFrameLatch;

    private static final String MIME_TYPE = "video/avc"; // H.264 Advanced Video Coding
    private static int mWidth;
    private static int mHeight;
    private static final int BIT_RATE = 16000000;
    private static final int FRAME_RATE = 30; // Frames per second

    private static final int I_FRAME_INTERVAL = 1;

    private int mGenerateIndex = 0;
    private int mTrackIndex;
    private boolean mNoMoreFrames = false;
    private boolean mAbort = false;

    int colorFormat;

    public interface IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback {
        void onEncodingComplete(File outputFile);
    }

    public BitmapToVideoEncoder(IBitmapToVideoEncoderCallback callback) {
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    public boolean isEncodingStarted() {
        return (mediaCodec != null) && (mediaMuxer != null) && !mNoMoreFrames && !mAbort;
    }

    public int getActiveBitmaps() {
        return mEncodeQueue.size();
    }

    public void startEncoding(int width, int height, File outputFile) {
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
        mOutputFile = outputFile;

        String outputFileString;
        try {
            outputFileString = outputFile.getCanonicalPath();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to get path for " + outputFile);
            return;
        }

        MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = selectCodec(MIME_TYPE);
        if (codecInfo == null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find an appropriate codec for " + MIME_TYPE);
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "found codec: " + codecInfo.getName());

        try {
            colorFormat = selectColorFormat(codecInfo, MIME_TYPE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            colorFormat = MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar;
        }

        try {
            mediaCodec = MediaCodec.createByCodecName(codecInfo.getName());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create MediaCodec " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        MediaFormat mediaFormat = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(MIME_TYPE, mWidth, mHeight);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, BIT_RATE);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, FRAME_RATE);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, colorFormat);
        mediaFormat.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, I_FRAME_INTERVAL);
        mediaCodec.configure(mediaFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE);
        mediaCodec.start();
        try {
            mediaMuxer = new MediaMuxer(outputFileString, MediaMuxer.OutputFormat.MUXER_OUTPUT_MPEG_4);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG,"MediaMuxer creation failed. " + e.getMessage());
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Initialization complete. Starting encoder...");

        Completable.fromAction(() -> encode())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe();
    }

    public void stopEncoding() {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to stop encoding since it never started");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping encoding");

        mNoMoreFrames = true;

        synchronized (mFrameSync) {
            if ((mNewFrameLatch != null) && (mNewFrameLatch.getCount() > 0)) {
                mNewFrameLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    public void abortEncoding() {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to abort encoding since it never started");
            return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG, "Aborting encoding");

        mNoMoreFrames = true;
        mAbort = true;
        mEncodeQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue(); // Drop all frames

        synchronized (mFrameSync) {
            if ((mNewFrameLatch != null) && (mNewFrameLatch.getCount() > 0)) {
                mNewFrameLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    public void queueFrame(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (mediaCodec == null || mediaMuxer == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Failed to queue frame. Encoding not started");
            return;
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Queueing frame");
        mEncodeQueue.add(bitmap);

        synchronized (mFrameSync) {
            if ((mNewFrameLatch != null) && (mNewFrameLatch.getCount() > 0)) {
                mNewFrameLatch.countDown();
            }
        }
    }

    private void encode() {

        Log.d(TAG, "Encoder started");

        while(true) {
            if (mNoMoreFrames && (mEncodeQueue.size() ==  0)) break;

            Bitmap bitmap = mEncodeQueue.poll();
            if (bitmap ==  null) {
                synchronized (mFrameSync) {
                    mNewFrameLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
                }

                try {
                    mNewFrameLatch.await();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

                bitmap = mEncodeQueue.poll();
            }

            if (bitmap == null) continue;

            byte[] byteConvertFrame = getNV21(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), bitmap);

            long TIMEOUT_USEC = 500000;
            int inputBufIndex = mediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(TIMEOUT_USEC);
            long ptsUsec = computePresentationTime(mGenerateIndex, FRAME_RATE);
            if (inputBufIndex >= 0) {
                final ByteBuffer inputBuffer = mediaCodec.getInputBuffer(inputBufIndex);
                inputBuffer.clear();
                inputBuffer.put(byteConvertFrame);
                mediaCodec.queueInputBuffer(inputBufIndex, 0, byteConvertFrame.length, ptsUsec, 0);
                mGenerateIndex++;
            }
            MediaCodec.BufferInfo mBufferInfo = new MediaCodec.BufferInfo();
            int encoderStatus = mediaCodec.dequeueOutputBuffer(mBufferInfo, TIMEOUT_USEC);
            if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                // no output available yet
                Log.e(TAG, "No output from encoder available");
            } else if (encoderStatus == MediaCodec.INFO_OUTPUT_FORMAT_CHANGED) {
                // not expected for an encoder
                MediaFormat newFormat = mediaCodec.getOutputFormat();
                mTrackIndex = mediaMuxer.addTrack(newFormat);
                mediaMuxer.start();
            } else if (encoderStatus < 0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "unexpected result from encoder.dequeueOutputBuffer: " + encoderStatus);
            } else if (mBufferInfo.size != 0) {
                ByteBuffer encodedData = mediaCodec.getOutputBuffer(encoderStatus);
                if (encodedData == null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "encoderOutputBuffer " + encoderStatus + " was null");
                } else {
                    encodedData.position(mBufferInfo.offset);
                    encodedData.limit(mBufferInfo.offset + mBufferInfo.size);
                    mediaMuxer.writeSampleData(mTrackIndex, encodedData, mBufferInfo);
                    mediaCodec.releaseOutputBuffer(encoderStatus, false);
                }
            }
        }

        release();

        if (mAbort) {
            mOutputFile.delete();
        } else {
            mCallback.onEncodingComplete(mOutputFile);
        }
    }

    private void release() {
        if (mediaCodec != null) {
            mediaCodec.stop();
            mediaCodec.release();
            mediaCodec = null;
            Log.d(TAG,"RELEASE CODEC");
        }
        if (mediaMuxer != null) {
            mediaMuxer.stop();
            mediaMuxer.release();
            mediaMuxer = null;
            Log.d(TAG,"RELEASE MUXER");
        }
    }

    private static MediaCodecInfo selectCodec(String mimeType) {
        int numCodecs = MediaCodecList.getCodecCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCodecs; i++) {
            MediaCodecInfo codecInfo = MediaCodecList.getCodecInfoAt(i);
            if (!codecInfo.isEncoder()) {
                continue;
            }
            String[] types = codecInfo.getSupportedTypes();
            for (int j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                if (types[j].equalsIgnoreCase(mimeType)) {
                    return codecInfo;
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private static int selectColorFormat(MediaCodecInfo codecInfo,
                                         String mimeType) {
        MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities capabilities = codecInfo
                .getCapabilitiesForType(mimeType);
        for (int i = 0; i < capabilities.colorFormats.length; i++) {
            int colorFormat = capabilities.colorFormats[i];
            if (isRecognizedFormat(colorFormat)) {
                return colorFormat;
            }
        }
        return 0; // not reached
    }

    private static boolean isRecognizedFormat(int colorFormat) {
        switch (colorFormat) {
            // these are the formats we know how to handle for
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420SemiPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
            case MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_TI_FormatYUV420PackedSemiPlanar:
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    private byte[] getNV21(int inputWidth, int inputHeight, Bitmap scaled) {

        int[] argb = new int[inputWidth * inputHeight];

        scaled.getPixels(argb, 0, inputWidth, 0, 0, inputWidth, inputHeight);

        byte[] yuv = new byte[inputWidth * inputHeight * 3 / 2];
        if (MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatYUV420Planar == colorFormat) {
            encodeYUV420P(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);
        } else {
            encodeYUV420SP(yuv, argb, inputWidth, inputHeight);
        }


        scaled.recycle();

        return yuv;
    }

    private void encodeYUV420SP(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        int yIndex = 0;
        int uvIndex = frameSize;

        int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {

                a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

                Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
                U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

                yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((U < 0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                    yuv420sp[uvIndex++] = (byte) ((V < 0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                }

                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void encodeYUV420P(byte[] yuv420sp, int[] argb, int width, int height) {
        final int frameSize = width * height;

        int yIndex = 0;
        int uIndex = frameSize;
        int vIndex = frameSize + frameSize/4;

        int a, R, G, B, Y, U, V;
        int index = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                a = (argb[index] & 0xff000000) >> 24; // a is not used obviously
                R = (argb[index] & 0xff0000) >> 16;
                G = (argb[index] & 0xff00) >> 8;
                B = (argb[index] & 0xff) >> 0;

                Y = ((66 * R + 129 * G + 25 * B + 128) >> 8) + 16;
                U = ((-38 * R - 74 * G + 112 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;
                V = ((112 * R - 94 * G - 18 * B + 128) >> 8) + 128;

                yuv420sp[yIndex++] = (byte) ((Y < 0) ? 0 : ((Y > 255) ? 255 : Y));
                if (j % 2 == 0 && index % 2 == 0) {
                    yuv420sp[uIndex++] = (byte) ((U < 0) ? 0 : ((U > 255) ? 255 : U));
                    yuv420sp[vIndex++] = (byte) ((V < 0) ? 0 : ((V > 255) ? 255 : V));
                }

                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    private long computePresentationTime(long frameIndex, int framerate) {
        return 132 + frameIndex * 1000000 / framerate;
    }
}
```

Comment: @jackson-daniel.Just wanted to drop a quick note to say thank you for your fantastic answer on Stack Overflow! Your insight really saved the day for me. Much appreciated!