# How to resize Yuv image on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, image, compression

please tell me how can I resize yuv image on android.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
mCameraView.myuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, mCameraView.myuvImage.getWidth(), mCameraView.myuvImage.getHeight()), 100, baos);
```

compressToJpeg method converts yuv image to jpeg. But doesn't resize converted JPEG by compression number when I write

```
mCameraView.myuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, mCameraView.myuvImage.getWidth(), mCameraView.myuvImage.getHeight()), 50, baos);
```

Comment: How does resizing affect eclipse or image compression? You don't need eclipse or image compression to resize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create a scaled bitmap. First, convert your bitmap to a bitmap image:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
YuvImage yuvImage = new YuvImage(mCameraView.myuvImage, PictureFormat.NV21, width, height, null);
yuvImage.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 50, out);
byte[] imageBytes = out.toByteArray();
Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.length);
```

Then, you can resize with:

```
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, newWidth, newHeight, true);
```

Comment: I dont need scaled Bitmap, I need Scaled YuvImage

Comment: @user2050649, in the constructor for YUVImage, there is parameters for width and height, can you try them? new YuvImage(mCamera.myuvImage, pictureformat, newWidth, newHeight,...)

Comment: @user2050649, try this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960247/convert-bitmap-array-to-yuv-ycbcr-nv21

Comment: I have tried width and height parameters YuvImages constructor, this way is wrong

Answer (score 0):

What I've found is probably not a really good approach, but that at least worked for me:

```
YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, size.width, size.height, null); //create YuvImage instance with initial size
ByteArrayOutputStream bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), jpegQuality, bao);
```

I have `aspect` value which is set outside. This value represents multiplier, how much do we decrease the scale, i.g. if `aspect == 1`, we use same resolution. If `aspect == 2` we divide image resolution by 2 and etc. Scaling required only in case if `aspect != 1`

```
if (aspect != 1) {
    int newWidth = image.getWidth() / aspect;
    int newHeight = image.getHeight() / aspect;
    byte[] scaledBitmapData = bitmapToByteArray(createScaledBitmap(bao.toByteArray(), newWidth, newHeight));
    bao = new ByteArrayOutputStream(scaledBitmapData.length);
    bao.write(scaledBitmapData, 0 , scaledBitmapData.length);

    image.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, newWidth, newHeight), jpegQuality, bao);
}
```

Utility methods:

```
public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(byte[] bitmapAsData, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapAsData, 0, bitmapAsData.length);
    return createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height);
}

public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int width, int height) {
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
}

public static byte[] bitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, JPEG_QUALITY, blob);
    return blob.toByteArray();
}
```

And this should do the trick.