# Android : how to convert back openCV Mat to byte array NV21?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, nv12-nv21

On Android , I use MediaCodec to create mp4 video file from captured images.

I am getting the OpenCV Mat data using

```
Image i = reader.acquireLatestImage();
ByteBuffer byteBuffer = i.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
byte[] bytes = new byte[byteBuffer.remaining()];
byteBuffer.get(bytes);
Mat mImageGrab = Imgcodecs.imdecode(new MatOfByte(bytes), Imgcodecs.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED); <= bytes from Image object
```

I have checked and the bitmap images are correctly showing(with some colors wrong translation)

this is the code that tests the Bitmaps:

```
Mat nv21 = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(mImageGrab, nv21, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2YUV_I420);<= NV21 is mat was created
Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mImageGrab.cols(), mImageGrab.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Mat bmpMat = new Mat();
Imgproc.cvtColor(nv21,bmpMat, Imgproc.COLOR_YUV420sp2RGB);<= transfer NV21 to Bitmap
Utils.matToBitmap(bmpMat, bmp);<= great bitmap result
```

However the MediaCodec mp4 expects byte array of NV21 image and not bitmap.
How can I transform the Mat to NV21? or the bitmap to NV21?
I want to perform some image processing to the images before sending those images to the MediaCodec.

I can also use the "encodeYUV420SP" function that was mentioned here
[Link to encode NV21](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13055615/2910319)
but it is too slow for video.

other option - render scripts - support for those supposes to be deprecated - so - I prefer not to.
But I am ready to try : bitmap to NV21 render script that is androidx compatible.()

Comment: Did you try posting on openCV platform? They can guide you better.

Comment: Consider using [sws_scale](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.bytedeco.javacpp.swscale/sws_scale). `sws_scale` supports conversions between most pixel formats. I know the [C interface](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.1/group__libsws.html) of `swscale`, but I don't know the JAVA interface. I don't know if there is support for Android, and I don't know the execution performance on ARM.

Comment: Dear Rotem, thanks - but as I said , I want to get closer to 30 FPS otherwise I would have use the Java link I mentioned "EncodeYUV420SP" which is faster the then the 100 ms of the sws_scale. (the sws_scale is part of the FFmpeg which is not really real time friendly). as written in this link https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2015-August/008348.html